Horror/Thriller movie with possessed old lady
I’m trying to figure out what movie this is—I remember it from my memory and I’m positive it exists. It’s a horror/thriller. Probably 2000-2010.
There’s a grandma type character that kind of looks like Dot Marie-Jones (Coach Beiste from Glee) and somehow she gets possessed and she wakes up in the middle of the night (eyes pitch black) slowly walking all throughout the house reaching outside and then there’s someone hiding in a panel like thing in the wall. 
Then the group of kids confront the possessed lady and one kid makes her recollect some distant memories and she recognizes him and asks: “Johnny?” But it’s not a woman’s voice its eerily similar to Robert Patrick’s voice (yunno the Dad from Bridge to Terabithia). I did all the research I can and now I need other’s help…

This sounds like it could potentially be The Taking Of Deborah Logan. 
Basically this story is about some kids conducting a documentory about an elderly woman, the Grandmother figure, and her struggles with "Alzheimer's". This of course results in the kids thinking something more sinister is going on.
There are issues, like there not being anyone called Johnny in the movie, but hopefully this can at least narrow the options down.
